# Need Help In configuring CruiseControl for Java Projects

Tags: java, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I am new to Crusie control. I have java projects that should be automated.
So could anyone please let me know how to configure CC for java projects.
Any kind of information regarding this is appreciatable.
Thank you,
Gang.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). CruiseControl is not worth the time IMHO. I only had a short experience with it and migrate it to Hudson. Everybody was happy and other people were able to setup projects easily.

Comment: +1 For using Hudson over CC.... a much more edifying experience. I'm still working on getting the butler's bow-tie to spin round on a successful build, though.

Comment: Same experience here, I'm using Hudson and never looking back!